# Add Hyperlink Image to Google Sheets email App Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I tried to add a Hyperlink Image to the end of my email message.
Attaching pdf and adding an image works well, but I have no clue how to do the same with a Hyperlink Image.

My previous sources were:
[Add Image to Google Sheets email App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199116/add-image-to-google-sheets-email-app-script)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage

Code:

```
function emailSend(){

// Auf das aktive Tabellenblatt zugreifen
var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invoice")
var as = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ffdhHQC4mpBTy8RzAcgXOrFv_fSXXXd3g1Ajx_EEcLguOvU").getSheetByName("Test") 
var is = SpreadsheetApp.openById("138nWL92xj1KTJdfhdh4iaOn_c62o5Qy-YynLFk1kAIky1TUF8").getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1")
var ks = SpreadsheetApp.openById("afdfd5_s1HQC4mpBTy8RzAcgXOrFv_fSXXXd3g1Ajx_EEcLguOvU").getSheetByName("Kunden")

var getData = Browser.inputBox('Sende Rechnungsemail', 'Schreib: OK', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
if (getData != 'cancel') 
{
  if (getData == 'OK')
  {
//Rechnungsverzeichnis
  var rechnungen = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HQC4mpBTy8RzAcgXOrFv_fSXXXd3g1Ajx_EEcLguOvU").getSheetByName("Kundenrechnungen");
  var row = 2;
  var column = 2;
  while(rechnungen.getRange(row, column).getValue() != '')
  {
    row++;

  }
  //is.getRange(18,4).setValue(rechnungen.getRange(row,1).getDisplayValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,column).setValue(new Date);
  rechnungen.getRange(row,3).setValue(as.getRange("A3").getValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,4).setValue(as.getRange("B3").getValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,5).setValue(as.getRange("C3").getValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,6).setValue(as.getRange("D3").getValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,7).setValue(as.getRange("K3").getValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,8).setValue(as.getRange("L3").getValue());
  rechnungen.getRange(row,9).setValue(as.getRange("M3").getValue());


// Den Betreff für die Email aus Zelle B2 auslesen
var betreff = as.getRange("B5").getValue();

// Die Emailadresse für den Empfänger aus Zelle B3 auslesen
//var emailEmpfaengerAdresse = as.getRange("G3").getValues();
    var emailEmpfaengerAdresse = "xxx@googlemail.com";

// Die Nachricht für die Email aus der Zelle B4 auslesen
var nachricht = as.getRange("B6").getValues();

var nachricht = "Hi"+ "<p>" + '<img src="cid:image"><br/>' + "</p>";

//Bild    
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/email-2.jpg").getBlob();


// Das Tabellenblatt als PDF der Variablen pdf zuweisen


var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById('55435hs1138nWL92xj1KTJiaOn_c62o5Qy-YynLFk1kAIky1TUF8').getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

// Den Anhang festlegen (Name des Anhangs, Inhalt, Typ)
var anhang = {fileName:(betreff+".pdf"),content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

//Nachfrage

// Senden der Email
var nachricht2 = nachricht.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailEmpfaengerAdresse, betreff, nachricht2,{ htmlBody: nachricht, inlineImages: {image:blob }, attachments:anhang});

//Sendung an Selbst
MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@xxx.com", (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B3").getValue()+" "+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A3").getValue() + " Rechung"), nachricht, {attachments:[anhang]}); 
  }
}

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to put the image of hyperlink to the email? Can you provide the output you expect?

Comment: I would like to add these little facebook and twitter hyperlink images in my email signature - under the companylogo and adress. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script and modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put an image with the hyperlink to the email when the email is sent using `MailApp.sendEmail()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? The image can be put with the hyperlink using HTML body. A simple sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, a logo is put as an image with the hyperlink.

```
var email = "###"; // Please set an email address.
var htmlBody = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" alt="sample" width="30%" height="30%"></a>';
MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject: "sample subject", body: "sample body", htmlBody: htmlBody});
```

- Also you can use GmailApp like `GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "sample subject", "sample body", {htmlBody: htmlBody})`.
- In this case, it is required to be able to see the email with the HTML body.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified and the image is put to the last of the HTML body, it became as follows.

Please add the following script before `MailApp.sendEmail(emailEmpfaengerAdresse, betreff, nachricht2,{ htmlBody: nachricht, inlineImages: {image:blob }, attachments:anhang});`.

```
nachricht += '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" alt="sample" width="30%" height="30%"></a>';
```

#### References:

- [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: @04k Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.