# Google Sheets Add an inline image to Gmail Message using CreateDraft Function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, gmail, inline-images

The company that I work for is moving to Google's mail client and Suite at the end of the month. My department uses an Excel form with some VBA coding that I learnt over lockdown. One of the form's fundamental operations, that I'm hoping to take across to Google Sheets, is when a button is clicked an email is created within the body of this email that is a screenshot of the form.

As I'm new to Javascript within Google Sheets, over the last few days I've found various methods and code to create an image and another to create a draft within Gmail. (It's important that the user of the form can see the email before it is sent - there's additional info to be added. Thus Gmail's auto-send feature isn't an option)

Why is the draft created, to email address is present, subject line, message text are too. But no image...

Any tips or pointers to code pages lovingly accepted

```
function sendit()
{
const range = "A1:H10";
const [header, ...values] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  .getRange(range)
  .getDisplayValues();
const table = Charts.newDataTable();
header.forEach((e) => table.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, e));
values.forEach((e) => table.addRow(e));
const blob = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataTable(table.build())
  .setDimensions(500, 500)
  .setOption("alternatingRowStyle", false)
  .build()
  .getBlob();

GmailApp.createDraft("xxxxxx", "current time", "The time is....", blob );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you wanna add an image the body should be html with an image tag.

Or

Or the image is added as an option so the method should be:

.createDraft(recipient, subject, body, {inlineImages: blob source})

(Options are add as objects)

See the docs

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createdraftrecipient,-subject,-body,-options

Maybe check this answer:

[Add Image to Google Sheets email App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199116/add-image-to-google-sheets-email-app-script)

Comment: Thank you for these help files and tried a few versions of your line and theirs.

For some reason it adds the png file as an attachment, but will look further into why

GmailApp.createDraft("xxxxxx","","",{ htmlBody: msgHtml, inlineImages:{image:blob}});

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Monkey Punky for your articles as got it to work with the code below.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getSheetByName("Main");

```
  var to = "xxxxxxxxxx.com";
  var message = '<img src="cid:logo" />';

 
const range = "A1:H10";
const [header, ...values] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  .getRange(range)
  .getDisplayValues();
const table = Charts.newDataTable();
header.forEach((e) => table.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, e));
values.forEach((e) => table.addRow(e));
var image  = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataTable(table.build())
  .setDimensions(500, 500)
  .setOption("alternatingRowStyle", false)
  .build()
  .getBlob();




  GmailApp.createDraft(
    to,
    "Subject",
    "",
    {
      inlineImages:{ logo:image },
      htmlBody:message
    }
  );
}
```